# Como pegar o valor de um @Html.TextBoxFor para um Input? asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Quero pegar o valor que esta no @Html.TextBoxFor é adicionar no input

```
<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
<label>Multiplicador 01:</label>
<input class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off" value= @Html.TextBoxFor(c => Model.VALOR01) type="number" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" id="valor1" name="valor1">
```

Answer (score 1):

@itasouza, acredito que nesse caso você possa utilizar o @Html.EditorFor, definindo o type dele como number, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```html
@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.VALOR01 , new { @type = "number", @id= "valor1", @step = "0.01", @name="valor1", @autocomplete="off"})
```

espero ter ajudado.

Abs

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.TextBoxFor()` gera um novo `<input>` para você. O correto é pegar diretamente o valor do *Model*:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off" value="@Model.VALOR01" type="number" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" id="valor1" name="valor1">
```